# How to calculate a new value from data in a raster file?

Tags: r, dataframe, gis, raster, shapefile

I have merged multiple raster files into a single data frame, and have two columns containing values for variables A and B. I need to compute the sum of A + B (so A + B = C). However, I am not sure how it would be possible to do this in a .RDS file.

I am somewhat out of my element here. I've tried doing this using normal commands like

```
C <- sum(A + B)
sum (A, B)
df %>% transmute(new_col = A + B)
```

This is just not working. I realize this is a basic question but I am just not sure how even to approach this.

Comment: Hi! Could you write in your message the output of `dput(object_name)` in order to see how does your data look like? I guess you have to use the name of the object instead of A and B which I suppose are column names.

Comment: `my_rast_df = readRDS('rast.RDS'); C = sum(my_rast_df$A, my_rast_df$B`, might work. Showing the readRDS step as @r18 suggests, clarifies things and becomes then more like a minimally reproducible example(MRE). If you want C as a column in your data.frame, `my_rast_df$C = sum(...` as above. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=3:1)
d$C <- d$A + d$B
d
#  A B C
#1 1 3 4
#2 2 2 4
#3 3 1 4
```